# How to invoke global commands while dot sourced

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Example:

dot sourcing openssl.exe to invoke commands in its context

```
. .\openssl.exe
OpenSSL> version -a
```

*Produces version information*

If I want clear the screen with traditional `cls`, it'll attempt to call it in the context of **OpenSSL**.

How do I invoke `cls`from the previous/non-dot sourced context.  Along with that, can you even "step back" from dot sourcing at all?

Comment: I don't think you can dot source exe in that sense. That is for scripts, functions etc.  You are truly running it. I don't believe i am incorrect in saying that you don't have access to the host in that context. If you were to run that as a job you would not lose the context but you would not be able to interact with it. Hoping you get a better answer than this though.

Comment: @Matt I think I get what you're saying.  Maybe I am using the dot sourcing in a way MS didn't intend on me using it.  It does get me the result(s) I wanted by being able to run commands against the executable, directly, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're invoking an interactive `openssl` session. In that session you can run OpenSSL (sub)commands, but not PowerShell cmdlets (since the environment is now OpenSSL, not PowerShell). Exit from `openssl` via `quit` to get back to PowerShell.

Dot-sourcing doesn't provide any benefits here, BTW. You can simply run `.\openssl` to get the same result.

You can also run `openssl` non-interactively by providing the subcommands on the commandline:

```
.\openssl version -a
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're best off by executing your commands in non-interactive mode: `. .\
openssl.exe version -a`. This will spit out the version information then leave you in your shell. Some programs have commands in interactive mode to call shell commands (MySQL comes to mind), but it doesn't look like OpenSSL supports it. You can exit the interactive mode and get back to your shell with the `quit` command.

Comment: +1 for `quit` command to retrun back to previous/non-dot sourced context.  That was super helpful and worked when I was dot sourced into OpenSSL.  However, I'm failing to get the non-interactive mode execution to work.  Is that a full-working example on your end?

Comment: I forgot a backslash in my answer. With that, it does work correctly.

Comment: Yes, it does, now.  Thank you.  Why bother using preceding `.`, though?  Just curious.

Comment: You don't need it. It does nothing in this case.